# Getting a value for the smallert interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table similar to this:

```
Value   StartDate   EndDate
```

I need to get the value where the interval between StartDate and EndDate is the smallest of the whole table. How do I express it in a WHERE clause?

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 value
FROM tbl1
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(ms, StartDate, EndDate)
```

If you have mode than one row with minimum difference you can use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES value
FROM tbl1
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(ms, StartDate, EndDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`DateDiff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) similar to this:

```
select value, startdate, enddate
from yourtable
where datediff(ss, startdate, enddate) = (select min(datediff(ss, startdate, enddate))
                                          from yourtable)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82b29/4)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Value
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(ms, StartDate, EndDate)
```

Note, there is no specification here about which Value to choose if there are multiple ones that have the same, minimum difference.

However, the DATEDIFF might not be great for performance if you have a larger number of rows in the table. If this is a frequent type of query, I would consider storing the difference as another column in the table and then use that to ORDER BY.